# JSON string to array change sort order

Tags: objective-c, json, nsmutablearray, nsjsonserialization

I just tried to decode my json string some thing like that below

```
{
    "Mon":" 03:00 PM - 11:55 PM",
    "Tue":" 03:00 PM - 11:55 PM",
    "Wed":" 03:00 PM - 11:55 PM",
    "Thu":" 03:00 PM - 11:55 PM",
    "Fri":" 03:00 PM - 11:55 PM",
    "Sat":" 03:00 PM - 11:55 PM",
    "Sun":" 03:00 PM - 11:55 PM"
}
```

To decode via

```
[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:[jsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
     options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers
           error:&jsonError]
```

Result of array oder changed..

```
{
Fri = " 03:00 PM - 11:55 PM";
Mon = " 03:00 PM - 11:55 PM";
Sat = " 03:00 PM - 11:55 PM";
Sun = " 03:00 PM - 11:55 PM";
Thu = " 03:00 PM - 11:55 PM";
Tue = " 03:00 PM - 11:55 PM";
Wed = " 03:00 PM - 11:55 PM";
}
```

I know best practice to add sort order on array, but that version is live now. can I sort array order on week days  without changing the array?

Comment: That's not an array. It's a dictionary. And dictionaries have no order.

Comment: As rmaddy said, dictionaries are unsorted, however in most of the cases this should not impact the program, since dictionaries like this are accessed in the order of the keys. The print order is not that important.